# How do I retrieve all usernames from 1 column and echo it in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

how do I return all username from one column in mysql DB in the example

```
username       age      height
  bob          20       5'1
  mary         29       4'0
  sue          25       5'8
```

how do I echo the everything in the username column
out put example I want `bob, mary, sue`

```
<?php

    include("db.php");


    $SQLSelect = $odb -> prepare("SELECT members, FROM username");
    $SQLSelect -> execute();
    while ($row =  $SQLSelect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $results = $row['members'];   
    }

    echo $results;


?>
```

Comment: What's `members`?

Comment: you have a syntax error in the query, an obvious one.

Comment: Remove the comma after members. Also you need to specify the table. Your query is selecting from a column.

Comment: You probably want to select username from members, and also you have a syntax error in your SQL query. Also you can't `echo` an array.

Comment: I think you have your query upside down actually along with that syntax error. I'm voting this as a typo.

Comment: use an array `$results[] = $row['members'];` and then `echo implode("\n", $results);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: Plus, you don't even need to prepare/execute, there's nothing *to* prepare; just run a regular `query()`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1: Build the user names string by looping through the fetched data and applying implode()

Notice the use of [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), which fetches all table rows.

```
<?php

include("db.php");

$sql = 'SELECT username FROM members';

$statement = $odb->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$fetchedData = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Just for testing: Print fetched data list.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($fetchedData, TRUE) . '</pre>';

// Build the user names array.
// ... by looping through the fetched data.
$usernamesArray = [];
foreach ($fetchedData as $item) {
    $usernamesArray[] = $item['username'];
}

// ... OR directly, by using array_column().
// $usernamesArray = array_column($fetchedData, 'username');
//
// Just for testing: Print the user names array.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($usernamesArray, TRUE) . '</pre>';

// Build the user names string.
$usernamesString = implode(',', $usernamesArray);

// Print the user names string.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($usernamesString, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

#### Method 2: Build the user names string by using the MySQL function group_concat()

Notice the use of [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), which fetches only one table row.

```
<?php

include("db.php");

$sql = 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username) AS usernames FROM members';

$statement = $odb->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$fetchedData = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Just for testing: Print fetched data list.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($fetchedData, TRUE) . '</pre>';

// Build the user names string.
$usernamesString = $fetchedData['usernames'];

// Print the user names string.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($usernamesString, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```